# The $n$th derivative of the $n$th spherical Bessel function

Tags: special-functions, bessel-functions, legendre-polynomials

I quote Problem 12.4.7 of the 5th edition of *Mathematical Methods for Physicists* by Arfken, Weber, and Harris:

> A plane wave may be expanded in a series of spherical waves by the Rayleigh equation:
> $$
> e^{ikr\cos\gamma} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n j_n(kr) P_n(\cos \gamma).
> $$
> Show that $a_n = i^n(2n+1)$. *Hint:* Use the orthogonality of the $P_n$ to solve for $a_n j_n(kr)$. Differentiate $n$ times with respect to $kr$ and set $r=0$ to eliminate the $r$-dependence. The remaining integral is
> $$
> \int_{-1}^1 x^n P_n(x) \mathrm dx = \frac{2^{n+1} (n!)^2}{(2n+1)!},
> $$
> as shown in a previous exercise.

Using the orthogonality condition for the Legendre polynomials (and substitution $x=\cos\gamma$), I obtained
$$
\frac{2}{2n+1} a_n j_n(kr) = \int_{-1}^1e^{ixkr}P_n(x)\mathrm dx,
$$
differentiating which $n$ times w.r.t. $kr$ gives
$$
\frac{2}{2n+1} a_n j_n^{(n)}(kr) = \int_{-1}^1(ix)^n e^{ixkr}P_n(x)\mathrm dx.
$$
My trouble comes from the $j_n^{(n)}(kr)$ bit. How does one differentiate the $n$th spherical Bessel function $n$ times? Or does setting $r=0$ automatically tell us its value?

Comment: There must be a mistake in your work, because 
when you obtained your second last equation$$\frac{2}{2n+1}a_n j_n(kr)=\int_{-1}^1 \mathrm e^{\mathrm ixkr}P_n(x)\mathrm dx$$
Can't you just immediately set $r=0$ to get
$$a_n=\frac{2n+1}{2}\frac{1}{j_n(0)}\int_{-1}^1 P_n(x)\mathrm dx$$
But that integral is zero....

Comment: @K.defaoite I think the problem with your argument is that $j_n(0) = 0$ for all $n > 0$, as can be seen here: 
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html.

Comment: Yes my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the spherical Bessel functions admit the [integral representation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.54)
$$j_n(z)=\frac{(-\mathrm i)^n}{2}\int_0^\pi \mathrm e^{\mathrm iz\cos\theta}P_n(\cos\theta)\sin\theta~\mathrm d\theta$$
Which, by the Leibniz rule, means
$$j_n^{(n)}(z)=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\pi \mathrm e^{\mathrm iz\cos\theta}\cos(\theta)^nP_n(\cos\theta)\sin\theta~\mathrm d\theta \\ j_n^{(n)}(0)=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\pi \cos(\theta)^n P_n(\cos\theta)\sin\theta~\mathrm d\theta$$
Which, by a change of variable $\cos\theta=x$ yields
$$j_n^{(n)}(0)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1 x^nP_n(x)\mathrm dx$$

Which you already know!

Comment: How did you go from $j^{(n)}_n$ to $j^{(0)}_n$? Where did $\sin \theta$ go?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! @Gary I think it was a typo, and the correct expression is $j_n^{(n)}(0)$, just setting $z = 0$. The $\sin\theta$ is also supposed to be there, which allows the change of variable.

Comment: This certainly works, though I don't think the authors intended it to be solved this way, since a few problems later we are asked to derive this integral representation for $j_n(z)$ from the result of this plane wave problem...

Comment: Whoops, typo. Sorry. I'll fix.

Comment: @Gary thanks for catching those mistakes. Fixed now

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @K.defaoite's answer, we can instead use the first formula in the [link](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.54) they provided:
$$
j_n(z) = \frac{z^n}{2^{n+1} n!}\int_0^\pi \cos(z\cos\theta) (\sin\theta)^{2n+1}\mathrm d \theta,
$$
which does show up earlier in the text (Problem 11.7.8). Differentiating this $n$ times gives
\begin{align}
j_n^{(n)}(z) &= \frac{1}{2^{n+1} n!}\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} (z^n)^{(k)}\left[\int_0^\pi \cos(z\cos\theta) (\sin\theta)^{2n+1}\mathrm d \theta\right]^{(n-k)} \\
&= \frac{1}{2^{n+1} n!}\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k} \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}z^{n-k} \int_0^\pi (\cos\theta)^{n-k}\cos(z\cos\theta) (\sin\theta)^{2n+1}\mathrm d \theta.
\end{align}
Setting $z=0$, all of the terms in the sum vanish except for the $k=n$ term, so
$$
j_n^{(n)}(0) = \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \int_0^\pi(\sin\theta)^{2n+1}\mathrm d \theta.
$$
This integral can be solved by a reduction formula to obtain
$$
j_n^{(n)}(0) = \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \frac{2^{2n+1}(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!} =  \frac{2^{n}(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!},
$$
which is the result of @K.defaoite's answer. This method also allows the formula for $\int_0^\pi x^nP_n(x)\mathrm dx$ to be used, instead of the integrals just cancelling out on both sides.

Comment: Sure, but, I don't see why this is better. What definition for $j_n$ are you given in the text?

Comment: @K.defaoite In the text, general Bessel functions are introduced first, and spherical Bessel functions are defined as 
$$
j_n(x) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2x}}J_{n+1/2}(x).
$$
The formula I gave is derived in an exercise from the integral representation of $J_\nu$. In addition, the formula you used is derived in Problem 12.4.9 from the result of Problem 12.4.7, which is the problem I asked about.
Also the $x^nP_n(x)$ integral cancels out on both sides if we use your formula, so the given formula is redundant. Once again, thanks for the answer!